# BASH script to subtract next line from previous line

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a script for parsing a file of timestamps, and I need to append the time elapsed on every line. For example, if my file is like this, each number being the minute an event takes place:

```
1
12
50
```

I want to append it to be

```
1 11
12 38
50
```

because the first event happened for 11 minutes until even 2 started at 12min, etc.

I'm having trouble accessing the next line, and also with the looping through the file in general. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Restrictions like bash only existing in linux, single thread functionality, or limitations of using "bash" scripting in windows environments, or the particular quirks of the 20 different bash terminals like Zsh, oh-my-zsh, terminal, konsole, etc?

Comment: @MikeHorstmann Bash exists under Linux, MacOS, Windows and many more. It can do parallel processing (GNU parallel, for example). Bash under Windows works just fine with Cygwin or MSYS/MSYS2. Bash is not a terminal. Zsh is not Bash. Terminal and konsole are not shells.

Comment: Bash exists under *nix sure.  Cygwin needs to be installed so that negates your point because you may not have installation permissions for a root application like cygwin to give it the power bash has.  It doesn't have VIM or NANO either.  It works fine under windows I'll give you that, but you need to elevate it by changing your env. vars. so you can run commands from anywhere in CLI again, permissions could be an issue.  FYI ISSUE == LIMITATION ("I'm not sure if you're hearing us correctly Bennie, this is Houston to Ben-Jammin") Also, tit for tat they're all text based terminals.

Comment: One other thing that I'm just "not sure" about so I ask in ignorance, say you were to use an alternative command line type language.  Let's say NodeJS.  Javascript is supported more than any other language currently, it's web friendly, it's evolving at an alarming rate, and it's fast.  Meanwhile, nodejs supports flightplan, forever, nodemon, has npm for including awesome pre-built processes, and is being taught literally EVERYWHERE.  It doesn't provide Answer A to Question A.  But an answer in NodeJS might provide Answer A-Z to Question A and questions B-Z yet to be posed.

Answer (score 7):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==1{p=$1;next} 
            {print p, $1-p; p=$1} 
         END{print p}' times

1 11
12 38
50
```

Answer (score 0):

With a tip of the hat to @karakfa

`perl -lne 'if ($.==1){$p=$_} else{print "$p ".($_-$p); $p=$_} END{print $p}' times`

`$.` is the line number (similar to awk's `NR`)
`$_` is the contents of the current line (similar to awk's `$1`)

output:

```
1 11
12 38
50
```

Answer (score 0):

BASH only - this is close, doesn't print the last by itself and you need to initialise the line variable which causes the zero at the start.  A more complicated script could read ahead, or someone might tell us how to offset the line indexing.

```
$ cat nums.txt
1  
12  
50  

$ line=0

$ for next in $(cat nums.txt); do echo $line $(expr $next - $line) ;\  
> line=$(echo $next) ; done  
0 1  
1 11  
12 38
```